# Installing NPM on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I am trying to install NPM on OSX Lion, I run this command:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

After asking to type "yes" and I do I get this:

```
All clean!
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js rm npm -g -f
node cli.js cache clean
Assertion failed: ((req->result == -1 && req->ptr == NULL) || (req->result >= 0 && req->ptr != NULL)), function uv_fs_req_cleanup, file src/unix/fs.c, line 89.
make: *** [clean] Abort trap: 6
node(21572,0x7fff73d64960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff772051000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
npm-install-20221.sh: line 211: 21572 Abort trap: 6           "$node" cli.js install -gf
It failed
```

Did some research and couldn't find anyone else with this exact issue. My node version is v.0.5.7-pre.

**EDIT**

For those looking how to install npmjs the url has changed to `https` only (url fixed above).

Comment: Uh, don't use v0.5.x of node, it's not stable. Try using v0.4.11, it's the latest stable.

Comment: I just installed it from the github master, how do I change the version?

Comment: `git checkout v0.4.11; ./configure; make; sudo make install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.

tjameson is right.

Install the **stable** version before installing npm.

Get the source code directly from node website:

[node-v0.4.11.tar.gz Source Code](http://nodejs.org/#download)